# What is the name of this rhetorical device

Tags: rhetorical-devices

What is the name of the rhetorical device where someone mentions a subject by stating that he or she will not mention it, as in "not to mention the fact that you have not paid me."

Comment: Type "apophasis" into the search box.

Comment: @deadrat If the OP knew that "apophasis" was the correct term, she wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @augurar And your point?  It wasn't a criticism; it was a suggestion

Answer (score 5):

[Preterition, proslepsis or apophasis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophasis), not to mention the many other derivatives with either (late) latin or greek root: praeteritio(n), occupatio on the one hand, cataphasis, paralipsis, parasiopesis on the  other hand.

While they vary with  sources, nuances might be:

- proslepsis: the pretence of passing over a subject while at the same time describing it fully,
- apophasis: an allusion to something by denying that it will be mentioned,
- praeterition: a rhetorical device in which the speaker emphasizes something by omitting it.

Comment: Upvote for actually using preterition/apophasis in your answer.

Comment: The comment section  is definitely not the place to emphasize my pleasure of being read

Comment: Now downvote for being pedantic. :-)